# Connection from UDP: [172.X.X.X]:44313->[172.X.X.X]:161SNMP logging Messages on SSH connection

Tags: linux-networking, logging, snmpd

Evey time we do an SNMP query.We get Connection from UDP: [172.X.X.X]:44313->[172.X.X.X]:161
Obviously, this is an annoyance rather than a problem

Is there away to hide them to see on SSH connection or disable them so that it will not show up on screen and keep logging in background?

Thanks in advance.